# Access ViewStub children using view binding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding, viewstub

How can I add the layout included in the viewStub to the activity view binding?

main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/stubContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/stub"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/content"
            android:layout="@layout/content_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And content_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to do something like `mainLayoutBinding.btn.setOnClickListener()`?
Or does it have to be using `findViewById()` after inflating the stub?

Comment: Did you find any solution yet for this?

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: Looking for this also...